# ASP.net Image buttons, Changing ImageUrl of iImage buttons

Tags: asp.net, image, asp-classic, imagebutton, imageurl

i have nearly 100 image buttons in a page, which calls a common function

protected void img_clock(object sender,ImageClickEventArgs e)

(which is in c#)

how can i set a common image using ImageUrl property of ImageButton to the image button which called this function or which is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast `sender` back to `ImageButton` and inspect it's `ImageUrl` value to retrieve image from the button that was clicked.

Comment: `protected void img_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) { var url = ((ImageButton)sender).ImageUrl; foreach (var img in YourImages) img.ImageUrl = url;`